# iOS: App Validation - Got Bad bundle identifier because of application extension bundle id format

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, archive, bundle-identifier

We have integrated share extensions as part of the new feature. For this, app bundle identifier is `com.company.name.product.mobile` and share extension bundle identifier is `com.company.name.product.mobile.Share.External.Information`.

After generating the Archive file, while validating the app through Xcode getting the below error.

**App Store Connect Operation Error**. Bad bundle identifier. The bundle identifier `com.company.name.product.mobile.Share.External.Information` of the application extension `ComanyName Mobile.app/PlugIns/Share External Information.appex` should start with the application's bundle identifier `com.company.name.product.mobile` and not contain more than one period `.` after the application's bundle ID.

i have already tried in StackOverflow and in another forum. I didn't find the solution for this.

am I doing anything wrong here?
after product bundle identifier we can have multiple words with `.` separated right in the extension?. In my case for extension after bundle Id it has three words with `.` separated like this "com.company.name.product.mobile.**Share.External.Information**". Is it correct? or it should be like  "com.company.name.product.mobile.**shareexternalinformation**".

Can any one please provide the solution for this ?